# Cellular Automaton on WPF

Tags: wpf, automata

currently im taking a Master degree course in Computer Sciences, and i´d like to implement a Cellular Automata in WPF. The rendering performance must be enough to display
a lattice (grid) containing 200,000 cells.

Since updating visuals is very slow in WPF (due to the visual and logical tree), maybe it's better to use old good Picturebox (GDI+) to do the rendering and WPF to implement the rest of the software. A second option would be to use pixel shaders (HLSL), but i'dont know if WPF supports multi-pass shaders.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check out the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).  The performance is decent, but nowhere near a shader can provide.  I'm not exactly sure what kind of shaders are supported, but I'd think it wouldn't be limited...

[Found this](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-using-effects.aspx) over on WindowsClient, it doesn't seem like multipass shaders are supported currently.  Again, its probably just a matter of time and demand on that code; it may have been added since the article was written.

Somebody +1 me for not mentioning the Game of Life.

Comment: It would be a shame if they are not supported, that would leave me with no choice but to use c++ / directX -_-. But first i´ll se the WriteableBitmap option

Thank you very much.

Comment: Update:  WPF4 supports PixelShader 3.0 now.

Comment: Everyone who cares about this needs go to http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions/suggestions/480961-add-gloweffect-and-multipass-shaders- and vote for adding Multipass shaders to WPF.